# How to go about creating a custom tool/adding special functionality for a web app

Tags: python, javascript, leaflet, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

In my soon to be developed web app, I will have an image service and also a feature service that is essentially an index to the image service, with all kinds of attributes. I would like for the user to be able to select a feature in the index layer, and then get a prompt to view the corresponding image in the image service. I only want the user to see the images that they have 'selected' by selecting features in the index layer. I know python pretty well but am still new with javascript. I was wondering about creating a custom tool in python and then publishing that as a GP service, but I'm unsure of how to manipulate feature/map services in python. I would assume this could be accomplished in javascript but I dont know enough to know how to do that. In terms of the web app, I would try to build it either in arcgis online or leaflet (which I am just learning). Wondering if anyone has some advice on a good approach to this task? I am going to start by investigating how to use the ArcGIS REST API in python.